# String array behavior: For Each operation in string array using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, string, foreach

I want to know the behavior of string array when using **For Each** loop in it. Consider following code:

```
Dim StringArray(499) As String
'fill in each element with random string

Dim count As Int32
Dim current As String

For Each current in StringArray
    'do something with current
    count = count + 1
    If count = 10
        Exit For
    End If
Next

're-enter the StringArray again
count = 0
For Each current in StringArray
    'do something with current
    count = count + 1
    If count = 10
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

As shown in the code above, if I need to access StringArray twice using **For Each loop**, is that true that **ALL** elements in StringArray will be loaded twice even though I only use 10 elements in each **For Each loop**? From performance point of view, is that advisable to use String array as data structure to store a list of strings that needed to be accessed multiple times, for example 20 times within a method?

Comment: Quick question: "**will be loaded twice**" what do you mean by loaded? Loaded from where?

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by "loaded"? You're just iterating over the array. That doesn't "load" anything - it just iterates over it. It doesn't make a copy, if that's what you were worried about.

In C# at least, a `foreach` loop over an expression which is known at compile-time to be an array will basically keep (and increment) an index and use direct array access. It won't even create an `IEnumerator(Of T)`. I would expect VB to behave the same way.

Note that LINQ can make your sample code simpler though:

```
' No need to declare any variables outside the loop
For Each current As String in StringArray.Take(10)
    ' Do something with current
Next
```

> From performance point of view, is that advisable to use String array as data structure to store a list of strings that needed to be accessed multiple times, for example 20 times within a method?

As opposed to what? It would be better to do that than to requery a database each of those times, for example. But it wouldn't be worth converting a `List(Of String)` to a string array...